# Python - key error when appending a list of dict to a nested defaultdict

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm trying to create a datastructure of nested dictionaries in Python. I read 2 relational sql-table-like csv files into dataframes and then convert them row by row into dictionaries. Inside these dictionaries I store dictionaries I created from another csv.

My code below works as long as I just store a dictionary directly in a dict key.

But what I actually want is that `data[id]['ticket']` contain a list of dictionaries. (1 customer could have multiple tickets)

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import collections

# Import csv into dataframe (maybe not necessesary)
df1 = pd.read_csv('customer.csv', sep=';', header=0, dtype=object, na_filter=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('tickets.csv', sep=';', header=0, dtype=object, na_filter=False)

df1['tickets'] = '' #create new empty column in dataframe 1

data = collections.defaultdict(dict)

# Convert initial dataframe to dictionary of dictionarys
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    row_dict = row.to_dict()
    data[row_dict['id']] = row_dict
    data[row_dict['id']]['tickets'] = []

# Convert each row of dataframe 2 to into dictionary and store on correct key of dict 1
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    row_dict = row.to_dict()
    data[row_dict['kundenid']]['tickets'].append(row_dict)

with open('json_file', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

With this code I get a key error for `tickets`. However when I use `data[row_dict['id']]['tickets'] = row_dict` to just append the dict to the key `tickets` the code works. I just need multiple dicts in this field.

What I finally want to achieve is a dictionary / JSON that looks like this:

```
     { "1111": {
         "id": "1111",
         "name": "",
         "adr": "",
         "tickets": [{
             "ticketid": "123545",
             "id": "1111"
         },
         {
             "ticketid": "123545",
             "id": "1111"
         }]}
     ....
     }
```

How can I store a list of dictionaries under the key `tickets`?

Edit: Some sample input data:

tickets.csv

```
id;ticketid;xyz;message
1;9;1;fgsgfs
2;8;2;gdfg
3;7;3;gfsfgfg
4;6;4;fgsfdgfd
5;5;5;dgsgd
6;4;6;dfgsgdf
7;3;7;dfgdhfd
```

Customer.csv

```
id;name;surname;address;XID
1;Mueller;Hans;42553;1
2;Meier;Peter;42873;2
3;Schmidt;Micha;42567;213
4;Pauli;Ulli;98790;432
5;Dick;Franz;45632;423
6;Doof;Udo;76543;233
7;Pang;Lars;43232;234
8;Peutz;Lee;11342;4234
```

Comment: Can you please include a few records from your csv file? While some may be able to visualize your code, mere mortals like me need some help.

Comment: Updated the question with some sample data. Hope that helps to undaerstand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution seems to work with input data provided (see below). Is there something I am missing?

As you point out, you need to test for keys in your second loop, as below. This is only apparent in your full dataset.

**Setup**

I have modified your data slightly so it demonstrates the problem better.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""id;name;surname;address;XID
1;Mueller;Hans;42553;1
2;Meier;Peter;42873;2
3;Schmidt;Micha;42567;213"""), sep=';')

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""id;ticketid;xyz;message
1;9;1;fgsgfs
1;8;2;gdfg
2;7;3;gfsfgfg
2;6;4;fgsfdgfd
3;5;5;dgsgd
3;4;6;dfgsgdf
3;3;7;dfgdhfd"""), sep=';')
```

**Solution**

```
data = defaultdict(dict)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    row_dict = row.to_dict()
    data[row_dict['id']] = row_dict
    data[row_dict['id']]['tickets'] = []

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    row_dict = row.to_dict()
    if row_dict['id'] in data:
        data[row_dict['id']]['tickets'].append(row_dict)
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {1: {'XID': 1,
              'address': 42553,
              'id': 1,
              'name': 'Mueller',
              'surname': 'Hans',
              'tickets': [{'id': 1, 'message': 'fgsgfs', 'ticketid': 9, 'xyz': 1},
                          {'id': 1, 'message': 'gdfg', 'ticketid': 8, 'xyz': 2}]},
             2: {'XID': 2,
              'address': 42873,
              'id': 2,
              'name': 'Meier',
              'surname': 'Peter',
              'tickets': [{'id': 2, 'message': 'gfsfgfg', 'ticketid': 7, 'xyz': 3},
                          {'id': 2, 'message': 'fgsfdgfd', 'ticketid': 6, 'xyz': 4}]},
             3: {'XID': 213,
              'address': 42567,
              'id': 3,
              'name': 'Schmidt',
              'surname': 'Micha',
              'tickets': [{'id': 3, 'message': 'dgsgd', 'ticketid': 5, 'xyz': 5},
                          {'id': 3, 'message': 'dfgsgdf', 'ticketid': 4, 'xyz': 6},
                          {'id': 3, 'message': 'dfgdhfd', 'ticketid': 3, 'xyz': 7}]}})
```

Comment: You are right! I realised that I had rows in my original csv 2 that do not have a matching key with id of csv 1. So in the second loop it can happen, that I try to append something to a key that's not initialised with a list.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti, I see, so you just need to add an `if` clause.. I have added this to the solution.

Comment: Right, that's how I solved it. Thanks for your support!